# Using styled-components with props from React component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled components in my react js project.
when constructing my styled component img, I want the background to be dependent on the props the component gets.
If i'm building a functional component I just use:

```
  const FramedImage = styled.img`
  background-size: cover;
  background: URL(${props.imageUrl});
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;`;
```

inside the component and it works.
but how can I achieve the same with class components? since I can't declare a const var inside the class itself, and out side of it, there is no `this.props`

Thanks!

Comment: you can declare const or let outside the class scope..and use inside the class

Comment: but then how can I use this.props in the const declaration outside the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass in a function to access **props** when defined outside the scope of the component. So in your case:

```
const FramedImage = styled.img`
  background-size: cover;
  background: URL(${props => props.imageUrl}); //use a function here instead
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

When `styled-components` encounters a function in the CSS template, it'll call it with the **props** assigned to the component.

Remember though this is refers to **props** assigned to the `FramedImage` component, so if you want to pass in **props** from it's parent component, you need to spread them in as such:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <FramedImage {...this.props} />
  }
}
```